# Cannot Get AJAX To Load

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

Here is HTML Nav:

```html
<ul class="sub-menu side-nav page-sidebar child-pages">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-9045" data-id="105"><a href="#History" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">History</span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-9046" data-id="185"><a href="#Strategic Plan" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Strategic Plan</span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-9047" data-id="183"><a href="#Financial Statements" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Financial Statements</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my PHP function:

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
function my_load_ajax_content(){
    $post_id = $_POST[ 'post_id' ];
    $post = get_post( $post_id, OBJECT);
    $response = array( apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_title ), apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) );
    echo '<div class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">'.$response[0].'</h1></div><div class="entry-content">'.$response[1].'</div>';
    die(1);
}
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Here's what's in `ajax.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).on('load',Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){

      if($('.current-menu-item > .sub-menu')){
        $('#sidebar-b').append($('.current-menu-item > .sub-menu').addClass('side-nav page-sidebar child-pages'));
        $("#sidebar-b .menu-item a:not(.pdf)").each(function(){
            var link_text = $(this).children('.menu-image-title').html();
            $(this).attr('href','#'+link_text);
        });
      }

    },300));

    $("#sidebar-b .menu-item .menu-image-title-after").click(function(e) {
        $("#loading-animation").show();
        var post_id = $(this).parent("li").attr("data-id");
        var ajaxURL = MyAjax.ajaxurl;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {"action":"load-content",post_id:post_id},
            success: function(response){
              $("#content > article").html(response);
              $("#loading-animation").hide();
              return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Additionally, when checking the `<head>` I noticed that my `ajax.js` script is not even loading even though it's being enqueued in my `PHP` function. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I've scoured Google for the last 3 hours and haven't found an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

1, you have to make sure that your script is triggered at the right element

2, you should change : "action":"load-content" to action: 'load-content' ( remove the double quote at action )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my Ajax problems still remain.  While I was able to get the script to load, it's not working as expected.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue the scripts by using below mentioned way, then it will be hooked with `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and load properly :

```
  function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This did add my ajax.js file to the <head> along with the <script> tag that includes the MyAjax var but, however, my ajax is still not loading the content as expected. What I can't seem to figure out is why it stopped working or what has broken it.  I'm not using Jetpack or anything that performs any Ajax-like functions on the front-end.

Comment: None. Not even when I include console.log(e) in ajax.js

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, after days and days of trial and error, I FINALLY got AJAX working! The secret was making my `ajax.js` an anonymous function.

```
(function($){

  $(document).on('click','.ajax-click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
    var ajaxURL = MyAjax.ajaxurl;

    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxURL,
      data:{ action: "load_content", post_id: post_id },
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#loading-animation").show();
        $("#content > article").fadeOut();
      },
      success: function(response){
        $("#content > article").html(response).fadeIn();
        $("#loading-animation").hide();
        return false;
      }
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

I kept everything in my `ajaxify.php` file as follows:

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_content', 'my_ajax_load_content', 99 );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load_content', 'my_ajax_load_content', 99 );
function my_ajax_load_content(){
    $post_id = $_POST[ 'post_id' ];
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $response = array( apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_title ), apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) );
    echo '<div class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">'.$response[0].'</h1></div><div class="entry-content">'.$response[1].'</div>';
    die(0);
}
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Quick reminder: Your `action` in `PHP` **MUST** match your action inside you `jQuery`. In my case it was `load_content` (e.g. `wp_ajax_nopriv_load_content`, `wp_ajax_load_content`, `data:{ action: "load_content" }`).

Hopefully this helps someone going through a similar issue with WordPress AJAX.